# Stop changing the postname into Wordpress back ito it's default

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

So I got a little confused.

The link should look like this:
https://www.mywebsite.com/why-do-you-need-a-passport/

I have set the URL Slug to "Why Do You Need a Passport" but the result is the default link.
like this:
https://www.mywebsite.com/?p=0023232/

What should I do to fix that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login Into Your WordPress Dashboard. (https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin)
2. Go Setting > Permalink > Common Settings
3. Change From "Plain" to "Post Name"
4. Save the changes

Note: If the link not change immediately try to click save settings 2 or 3 times, it can happen on WordPress Older Versions.

Comment: @Lkwin Ko Ko, Unfortunately, I am not one of the admins of the website so I'm pretty much limited to posts.

Comment: Ok I see, so you need to ask the admin user to change the Permalink settings. But please note that if other services are used based on that wordpress site, be careful. It can crash other services. If it is alone it's safe to change setting. I hope the admin already know.